# Open Google Docs in Browser

Tags: samsung-dex, google-docs

I'm using Samsung Dex on a Note 9 and would like to open Google Docs in Chrome (or any other browser) instead of the Google Docs app.

Otherwise I can't use certain plug-ins like reference managers.

I tried uninstalling docs, tried different browsers, tried to change the default action for Google docs links and tried to activate the desktop mode where possible but I still couldn't access the desktop mode of Google Docs that I would see on Windows. I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use this for most Google apps not just Google Docs**

- Install [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox)
- Install [Google Shortcut](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/google-shortcuts-all-google-se/) add-on. Tap the 3 dots (**`⋮`**) menu to reveal the side bar →Add-ons→Google Shortcut. Tap to open →options. From the left pane tap Google Docs and it will appear on the right pane.

(Click to enlarge screen shots )

[image: IMG:]

- Open a new tab and from 3 dots menu locate *App Launcher* (see screen shot).

[image: IMG:]

- Tap on App Launcher to reveal Google Docs icon. Tap on that to see your docs and open them!

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I could get Google Docs to work on Dex that way, the only problem is that the UI is very large on Dex.

Comment: Dex is the desktop environment for Samsung phones for working with an external display. I'm trying to scale the GUI, not the font. Anyway, I found out that I can also launch Google Docs in the browser if I use Chrome (not any other browser) in desktop mode. The GUI looks fine there.